# How to model a cooling system?

Tags: thermodynamics, cooling

Suppose a system with a coolant, a pump, a radiator, and a constant power load object with some constant heat capacity. How can we model the dependence of the load temperature on coolant flow rate (or pump power), radiator size, and radiator air flow rate? I am mainly interested in steady state conditions.

Comment: A picture would be very helpful.  As stated, your problem statement is VERY "open-ended".

Comment: What do you understand by 'power load'?

Comment: David, yes, I am just looking for approximate scaling laws and constants, or perhaps rules of thumb. Did you want a picture of a real system or a diagram ?

Comment: Gert, the load of constant power would be an object which has a constant power of heat added to it. That is, heat is added at a constant rate.

Comment: I would suggest to use one of the many technical (thermodynamic) process simulation packages that are out there. Unless you are constrained by "not invented here", this is a solved engineering numerics problem.

Comment: Yes.  This is a straightforward problem in heat transfer using a finned tube heat exchanger with air blowing on the outside and coolant flowing through the inside of the tubes.  It's has got to be found in a book on automotive engineering.